# Debugging children using valgrind

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

In short, `valgrind` is not producing line numbers for new processes, but it does show line numbers on the main application. Note, the main application and all newly spawned processes are the same application.

I am running `valgrind` with the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --trace-children=yes --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 ./myapp
```

I then run `gdb` to start the application.

```
gdb ./myapp
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
```

While my application is running valgrind will output the following message when a new process is spawned.

```
==19414== (action at startup) vgdb me ... 
==19414== 
==19414== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==19414==   /path/to/gdb ./myapp
==19414== and then give GDB the following command
==19414==   target remote | /usr/local/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=19414
==19414== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==19414==
```

Here's where I run into the issue. I open up a new instance of `gdb` and running the command. However, I get an error.

```
(gdb) target remote | /usr/local/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=18920
Remote debugging using | /usr/local/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=18920
relaying data between gdb and process 18920
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-freebsd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-freebsd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libjson-c.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libm.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libpq.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libthr.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libssl.so.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libheimntlm.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libhx509.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libcrypto.so.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libasn1.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libwind.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libheimbase.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libroken.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libcrypt.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libz.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libgssapi.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libintl.so.8...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/private/libheimipcc.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
0x00000000059aaa2a in syscall () from /lib/libc.so.7
(gdb) c
Continuing.
syscall failed: Bad file descriptor
close from_pid
Remote connection closed
```

So that tells me it's not finding debug information. `valgrind` was installed using a package so it wasn't configured for debug. However, I'm not seeing my application listed. I am seeing libraries I am using such as `libcurl` and `libjson-c`, but not my application.

My next test was running `valgrind` without `gdb`.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --trace-children=yes ./myapp
```

This time `valgrind` will produce the errors for new processes, but I am unable to see my line numbers of the new processes. I can see the line numbers when I get an error on the main application. I have a feeling not being able to debug the new process in `gdb` is because of the issue of not seeing line numbers without `gdb`.

Comment: If you start gdb using  'gdb <your_application>, then it is loading the debuginfo of your program at gdb start. If you start gdb without giving an argument, you must have a recent gdb and a recent valgrind to have gdb loading <your_application> debug info automatically. The message 'close from_pid' is an error report by vgdb. It looks like you use valgrind on freebsd, which is not upstream. You might try to see what is happening in vgdb using vgdb --pid=xxxxxx -d -d -d 2>v.out   and examining the v.out tracing.